# Fill in an incomplete outline of an image

Tags: image-processing, image

I have an outline which I have extracted from an image, which may well not entirely closed, for instance:

[image]

I now want to fill the inside of this, as another image, using the convex hull if it is not closed.

For instance:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC9ym.png"];
ConvexHullMesh[PixelValuePositions[img, 1]]
```

[image: Convex hull mesh]

is the right shape, but is a mesh rather than an image and now in a different coordinate system.

`FillingTransform` doesn't seem to work, presumably because the outline is not complete. `ComponentMeasurements[img, "ConvexVertices"]` gives me the points that make up the convex hull, but I can't manage to fill in the middle in an easy (and ideally fast way).

Rasterizing the `ConvexHullMesh` has been suggested in the comments, but that doesn't appear to work for me, as the `ConvexHullMesh` zooms into the image.

```
HighlightImage[Rasterize[ConvexHullMesh[PixelValuePositions[img, 1]], 
    RasterSize -> ImageDimensions[img]], img]
```

[image: Rasterized image with original]

```
$Version
(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)
```

Comment: If `ConvexHullMesh` works as desired, what about
`Rasterize[ConvexHullMesh[PixelValuePositions[img, 1]], RasterSize -> ImageDimensions[img]]`?

Comment: @TheoTiger, because it is not in the same coordinate system, see `HighlightImage[
 ColorNegate@
  Binarize[Rasterize[ConvexHullMesh[PixelValuePositions[img, 1]], 
    RasterSize -> ImageDimensions[img]]], img]` - the rasterized image is now zoomed in.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, they are in the same coordinate system for me. They overlap nicely. I'm on Mma `11.3` btw. Can you add an image of your `HighlightImage` to the question?

Comment: @Theo, strange, as they definitely don't for me, on 11.3 too.

Comment: The `ConvextHullMesh` is just slightly larger, which seems logical since it needs to contain all the points.

Comment: @TheoTiger, not just a little larger for me, the ConvexHullMesh has definitely zoomed in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pvp = PixelValuePositions[img, 1];
Graphics[{LightBlue, EdgeForm[Blue], Polygon[pvp[[FindShortestTour[pvp][[2]]]]]}]
```

[image]

```
ImageAdd[img, 
 Graphics[{Red, EdgeForm[Blue], Polygon[pvp[[FindShortestTour[pvp][[2]]]]]}, 
  PlotRange -> Thread[{0, ImageDimensions[img]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make it be the same dimensions as the original image? So things like `ImageAdd[img, 
 Graphics[{Red, Polygon[pvp[[FindShortestTour[pvp][[2]]]]]}]]` work properly.

Comment: @KraZug, please see the updated version.

Comment: Thank you, I think that does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 7):

First, extract the points from the image and take the convex hull mesh:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC9ym.png"];
allpts = PixelValuePositions[img, 1];
chmesh = ConvexHullMesh@allpts;
```

Use `MeshPrimitives` to extract the boundary lines.  Extract their endpoints.  Since the endpoints are not unique, take every other end point to obtain a set of unique points on the convex hull:

```
endpts = Flatten[MeshPrimitives[chmesh, 1] /. Line -> List, 2];
hullpts = Take[endpts, {1, -1, 2}];
```

Plot the results:

```
Graphics[{Black, PointSize[1/300], Point@allpts,
  Red, Line[hullpts],
  Opacity[1/8], Blue, FilledCurve@Line[hullpts] }]
```

[image]

***EDIT:***

What we are really after is an image of the filled curve that will overlay the original image, which has `ImageDimensions` of {1024,1024}.  We want to use `ImagePadding` to position the filled image on the original image.  The amount of padding is first estimated by looking at the minimum and maximum coordinates in `allpts`, then adjusting by a small $\delta$. Instead of the original image let's work with its negative.

```
MinMax/@Transpose[allpts]
δ = 16;
filled = Image[Graphics[
    {Opacity[1/8], Red, FilledCurve@Line[hullpts]},
    ImagePadding -> {{137 - δ, 
       1024 - 895 - δ}, {114 - δ, 
       1024 - 917 - δ}}], 
   ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[reverse]];
reverse = ColorNegate[img];
Show[{reverse, filled}, ImageSize -> 200]

(*   {{137, 895}, {114, 917}}   *)
```

[image]

To verify that $\delta = 16$ is optimal, we can use `ImageTake` to zoom in on the left edge, say,

```
β = 20;
Show[ImageTake[#, {512 - β, 512 + β}, {137 - β, 
     137 + β}] & /@ {reverse, filled}, ImageSize -> 200, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Here we have zoomed in on both the reverse image and the filled image at about 137 pixels from the left and 512 pixels from the top.  Our view frame is $2\beta$ square.  We could adjust $\delta$ a little to see how the filled image shifts relative to the reverse image.  We can also zoom in to check the fit at other critical points of the image.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out that `MorphologicalComponents` will give the convex hull:

```
imageHull = Image@MorphologicalComponents[img, Method -> "ConvexHull"]
```

[image]

```
HighlightImage[imageHull, img]
```

[image]

I am still interested in a solution that doesn't require ConvexHull for the whole image, but just fills in the missing hole where there is a gap.

Comment: "I am still interested in a solution that doesn't require ConvexHull for the whole image, but just fills in the missing hole where there is a gap."

You mean you don't want the convex hull, just the missing line segment? Try getting the convex hull anyway and then computing the boundary.

Comment: @kajacx, I want an image that contains the filled inside of the line. Where the line is intact but non-convex, the ConvexHull will expand out of it. Where there are breaks, I'd like the shortest straight line to be taken.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments, `ConvexHullMesh` works as desired for me **on Windows**.

### Windows 7

```
$Version
(* "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC9ym.png"];
meshraster = Rasterize[ConvexHullMesh[PixelValuePositions[img, 1]], RasterSize -> ImageDimensions[img]];
HighlightImage[meshraster, img]
```

[image: ConvexHull on Windows 7]

### Mac OS

I just ran it on Mac OS 10.13. I have no words.

```
$Version
(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)
```

[image: ConvexHull on Mac OS]

Comment: Thanks. That is rather more wider than the original line than I can accept though, even if I understood what was going on between Windows and Mac.

Comment: See my edit above - I can reproduce this strange behaviour on Mac OS. I have no idea what is happening there. I think this could be reported to Wolfram Support as bug.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the device pixel scaling ("DPI settings")? I am on a 1200p non-Retina display, however.

Comment: Hah, something like that presumably. Your image for the same code on a mac is zoomed out, while mine is zoomed in!

Comment: The help says: "Images generated by Rasterize can vary slightly from one computer system to another, mainly as a result of different fonts and anti-aliasing procedures." - slightly! Reported as a bug.

Comment: While I understand that font rendering and anti-aliasing can be different, the overall size should not change IMO. Thank you for reporting.

Comment: My response from Wolfram says that "The output of Rasterize is dependent upon the size of the notebook it is being evaluated in. ", which explains the difference.