# How can I generate a convex hull of a binary image?

Tags: image-processing

I have a binary image (`img`) as shown below and I wish to generate a convex hull of the white region.

[image]

I tried to use `ConvexHullMesh` but could not get the desired size with the background to fit into the original image.

```
cv = ComponentMeasurements[
   FillingTransform[scleraRough1], {"ConvexVertices", "Mask"}];
cvScaled = Rescale@cv[[1, 2, 1]];
Rasterize@ConvexHullMesh[cvScaled]
```

How can I generate the desired convex hull (a binary mask surrounded by the background)?

and I get [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you can do this straight away with:

```
Image@MorphologicalComponents[img, Method -> "ConvexHull"]
```

See this answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189196/72682

---

It's a bit awkward, but you can get them to line up using `Inset`. I've shown the boundary below, but if you want the face, just remove the `RegionBoundary`. I also used `ImageValuePositions` which are pixel centered offset by 0.5, rather than `PixelValuePositions`.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ndPk.png"] // Binarize;
(* remove the border *)
img = ImageTake[img, {2, -2}, {2, -2}];
dims = ImageDimensions[img];
cvx = ConvexHullMesh[ImageValuePositions[img, 1]];
Graphics[{Inset[img, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, dims], Red, RegionBoundary[cvx]},
  PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRange -> Transpose@{{0, 0}, dims}]
```

[image: boundary]

To get the image mask you could do:

```
gr = Graphics[{Inset[img, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, dims], White, cvx}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRange -> Transpose@{{0, 0}, dims}];
Image[gr, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]]
```

[image: convex hull mask]

Comment: Thanks for the straight forward way. When I searched for the `ConvexHull` in the documentation, I found that it is obsolete now. I didn't know that it can be used in the way you have mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @Majis yes, the simpler one is the best approach too because it fully contains the image, unlike my method with `Inset` and `ImageValuePositions`. You can verify with: `ImageCompose[
 ColorReplace[
  Image@MorphologicalComponents[img, Method -> "ConvexHull"], {1 -> 
    Red}],
 ColorReplace[img, 0 -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 0]]
 ]`. There are no partial pixels sticking out the sides.